# Publish option in Sitecore Helix visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, vs-helix-extension

By default, while creating a project, this extension installs docker deploy configurations in the visual studio solution. Do we need to manually modify config files if we just want to deploy all files to the local `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` directory on the vanilla `Sitecore 10.2` instance? One of the reasons could be because now this extension shows `Sitecore 10.2` templates but the older version had `Sitecore XP 9.3` templates. Is it possible to install the older version of the extension so that it can bring config files to deploy to the root directory

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersLaublaubplusco.SitecoreHelixVisualStudioTemplates

Comment: You can use the extension in the [course files](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/building-sitecore-helix-website/table-of-contents) that you mentioned. It is an older version which you can install directly by running.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit Helix Templates by yourself, no need to install older version. You need:

1. Install extension
2. Try to create new Helix project
3. Click on settings: you will see folder, where your templates were installed
   [image]
4. You will be able to see and change(if required) location of templates
5. You can open project by path from step 4 (`c:\projects\helix.templates\` by default) and modify how you want. Add/remove/change publishing templates. Add/remove additional files. Anything that you need for your project.

Comment: Actually I was followings [this course ](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/building-sitecore-helix-website/table-of-contents) but now as per latest response from course I was able to proceed after installing the VSIX from old course